# How to setup Ethernet for local connection with a camera

Tags: networking, ethernet, camera

I am using Ubuntu 1804 on a Jetson Nano. If I plug in my network cable from the router, I can access the internet and everything works fine. However, if I plug in the network cable connecting my 3d camera (so there's no more internet connection, only local to the camera), I can not ping the camera's ip: the error `connect: Network is unreachable` occurs.

If I connect the same camera using the same cable with a windows pc, I can ping the camera.

Can anybody help me how to configure ubuntu or what to do? Sorry, I am quite new to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is running into the same problem, in my case the solution was very simpel: I just changed the ethernet network settings -> link negotiation from `automatic` to `disable`, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in my case I changed the connection to "link-local-only".

```
sudo nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname eth0
nmcli connection modify ethernet-eth0 ipv4.method link-local
nmcli connection up ethernet-eth0
```